# TeamCity shows less tests passed for long similar test names because of cropping

Tags: unit-testing, teamcity

I have unit test with two test cases (I use NUnit). Test case argument is long string condition.
For example:

```
[TestCase("condition1 AND condition2 AND ... condition3")]
[TestCase("condition1 AND condition2 AND ... condition4")]
```

In TeamCity Build->Tests output I can see than only 1 test passed and status OK (2 runs). But it should show that 2 tests passed because they are independent test cases.

As I understand the problem is that TeamCity identifies tests by their names but crops long names. So in my case name is the same for both tests, it cropped on the word "AND" and contains no last condition. Looks like:

```
TestClass.TestName("condition1 AND condition2 AND
```

I think it's TeamCity bug/feature but maybe someone knows if it can be configurable or fixed somehow? Because I want to see 2 tests passed instead of 1 as a result. Of course I can set custom name for my test cases in code but I don't want to fix it this way.
TeamCity version 9.1.30.476.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be a limitation of TeamCity. Refer to [Test Results at TeamCity UI groups long name tests](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36431695/1986541)