# Test Results at TeamCity UI groups long name tests

Tags: teamcity

My TeamCity configuration only show 255 characters at UI, Test column from the Tests tab, so if my tests share the first 255 characters of the path, they appears at status column like "OK (4 runs)" or "Failure (1 of 4)", how can I customize this limit?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this limit used in database schema and cannot be modified. See related issues in our tracker: [TW-10480](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-10480) and [TW-44130](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-44130).